# javascript namespacing TypeError: blah is not a function

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've got an html file a javascript file and jquery.

in the javascript I have a namespaced function with in the return an object with a function I would like to call from outside. This is to create 'public' and 'private' functions.

In the HTML I want to trigger this function which is in the return object.
However it does not recognize it. In the console I get this error:

TypeError: BATCH.SendSMS.uploadFiles is not a function

It should work, I've done it before, so I must be doing something wrong. Can you please have a look:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Batch SMS</title>
    <style media="all" type="text/css">
        @import url("main.css");
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/batchsms.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
    <div id="fields">

        <div>
            <span>Sender: </span>
            <select id="sender">
                <option value="">Maak keuze</option>
                <option value="Sender1">Sender 1</option>
                <option value="Sender2">Sender 2</option>
                <option value="Sender3">Sender 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <div>
            <span>Phone file:</span>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="file">
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Appointment file:</span>
            <input id="appointment" name="appointment" type="file">
        </div>

        <div>
            <span></span>
            <input type="button" value="Upload Files" onclick="BATCH.SendSMS.uploadFiles();">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var BATCH = BATCH || {};
BATCH.SendSMS = function() {

    var error = "";

    var setError = function() {
        $('#main').prepend($('<div>').append(error));
    };

    return {
        uploadFiles: function() {

            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/upload.php",

                 data: formData,
                 dataType: "json",

                 success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data);
                 },

                 error: function(data){
                     console.log(data);
                 },

                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false
             });

         }
     };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even better solution.

I should have returned the function to itself.

Example:

```
BATCH.SendSMS = function() {

    //do stuff here

}();
```

This last '()' will ensure me that I can call:

BATCH.SendSMS.uploadFiles()

Answer (score 3):

You'll want `BATCH.SendSMS().uploadFiles()`.

This is because `BATCH.SendSMS` is a function returning the object with the `uploadFiles` function, not the object itself.

Comment: yep that works... though I did this without the () as well... but that was in javascript, calling another script. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: In the code you provided above it would extremely tricky, if it's even possible, to access properties of the return object without calling the function.